# SFTP over gateway

Tags: ssh, sftp, gateway

I'm trying to connect to a server (with SFTP) through a gateway, but I can't find a solution with SSH tunnelling.
This is how it should work :

- Connect to ssh **gatewayserver** using user1/password1
- sudo su - user2 (only command I can execute using sudo)
- ssh **finalserver** (With private key of user2)
- sudo su - finaluser

And I can't copy user2 private key anywhere since it will be considered as unsecure

Do you have any idea how can configure an SFTP/SCP client (using Mobaxterm, Putty, Winscp or another client) following these steps ?

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP supports tunneling though other SSH server natively.

See the [Tunnel page of its Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

[image: Tunnel page]

---

For other clients, you can setup the tunnel using PuTTY and connect though it.

See *my* guide for [tunneling SFTP/SCP session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty).